# how to prevent input/output errors when ffmpeg to sshfs mounted fs and connection is lost

Tags: linux, ssh, video, ffmpeg, sshfs

I'm recording video across the network using ffmpeg to a filesystem mounted by sshfs.  I'm consistently having the issue that if my machine goes to sleep, the ssh connection drops and has to reconnect (I'm using the `-o reconnect` option to sshfs so I don't lose connection).  For most processes that are accessing the filesystem, they don't seem to even notice the momentary disconnection, it is as if the filesystem is simply taking a long time until the timeout is reached and it reconnects.

However, with ffmpeg I have a real issue, because instead of just hanging for a bit, I get this message:

```
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Input/output error
```

And with that ffmpeg unceremoniously gives up and exits, leaving a video file that is unplayable!

I have tried various options to ffmpeg, e.g. `-reconnect 1 -reconnect_at_eof 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 4962 -timeout 2000000000`.  When I try these options, the behavior is the same, except instead of a single input/ouput error, it also has a message like this:

```
Last message repeated 135 times

Error writing trailer of /sshfs/test.mp4: Input/output error
```

This all happens in a very short period of time, as if it's retrying some random number of times (I have seen it as low as 39) without any delay in between.

I don't know if the issue is in sshfs, or ffmpeg, but I need to be able to reliably write video and not have it creating unplayable video files, as this is on a device that goes to sleep regularly.  How can I do this?

Note: I see this issue both with the default ffmpeg binary from the Ubuntu 18.04 package, and from the 64-bit pre-compiled static version 4.2.2 downloaded directly from the ffmpeg.org downloads page.

Update: I'm starting to think it's the fault of sshfs, because if I do something like `cat /dev/zero > /sshfs/tmp.mp4` and the connection dies, it doesn't reconnect (due to the cat in progress) and even if it does reconnect (because I attempt another access to poke it to reconnect) the cat stays hung.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The culprit is sshfs, and the problem isn't going to be fixed.

I found [this thread](https://sourceforge.net/p/fuse/mailman/message/19808106/) from 12 years ago where it is explicitly said that this is expected behavior, and that:

```
This is a limitation of the reconnect in sshfs, which really
wasn't designed to gracefully handle such "hot" reconnects.  It's
mostly useful for the case when disconnection happens during no
activity.
```

Since this isn't a real answer (a *real* answer would provide an actual solution to your problem instead of making excuses about how it was impossible, which it really *isn't* but nobody cares enough to actually fix the problem) I am going to downvote my own answer.

Edit: Ok, I *tried* to downvote, but it wouldn't let me. I can understand why one can't upvote their own answer, but not why they can't downvote.  Somebody please downvote this answer for me.

Comment: There's no requirement that all issues have a solution or workaround, so a statement of limitations is fine.